# Why am I getting an invalid syntax error in a for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error

I am writing a python program to display the elements of a dictionary, but when I run the program I am receiving an Invalid Syntax error. I am getting the error on the 3rd to last line in the for loop. Does anyone know why this error is coming up?

```
def main():
    my_contacts = {"Fred":7239591, "Mary":3841212, "Bob":3841212, \
               "Sarch":2213278}
    if 'Fred' in my_contacts:
        print('Number for Fred', my_contacts["Fred"])
    else:
        print("Fred is not in my_contacts list.")
    nameList = findName(my_contacts, 3841212)
    print("Names for 3841212:", end = " ")
    for name in nameList:
        print(name, end=" ")
    print()
    printAll(my_contacts)

def findName(contacts, number):
    nameList = []
    for name in contacts:
        if contacts[name]==number:
            nameList.append(name)
    return nameList

def printAll(contacts):
    print("All names and numbers")
    for key in sorted contacts:
        print(key.contacts[key])
main()
```

Comment: `sorted contacts`?

Comment: @user2357112 yes... Is that incorrect?

Comment: if you remove sorted from the printAll for, you get a different error :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Change your `printAll` function as following -

```
def printAll(contacts):
    print("All names and numbers")
    for key in sorted(contacts):
        print(key, contacts[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
def main():
    my_contacts = {"Fred":7239591, "Mary":3841212, "Bob":3841212, \
               "Sarch":2213278}
    if 'Fred' in my_contacts:
        print('Number for Fred', my_contacts["Fred"])
    else:
        print("Fred is not in my_contacts list.")
    nameList = findName(my_contacts, 3841212)
    print("Names for 3841212:", end = " ")
    for name in nameList:
        print(name, end=" ")
    print()
    printAll(my_contacts)

def findName(contacts, number):
    nameList = []
    for name in contacts:
        if contacts[name]==number:
            nameList.append(name)
    return nameList

def printAll(contacts):
    print("All names and numbers")
    for key in sorted(contacts):
      print(key, contacts[key])
main()
```

prints this output :

```
Number for Fred 7239591
Names for 3841212: Mary Bob 
All names and numbers
Bob 3841212
Fred 7239591
Mary 3841212
Sarch 2213278
```

Comment: if you want to sort them before printing, tell me and I will edit my answer

Comment: Yes, the output should be sorted.

Comment: Should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

See the problems of your code , indicated with arrow keys -

``````````````````
def printAll(contacts):
    print("All names and numbers")
                -----------------
    for key in | sorted contacts: |  <-
                ````````````````` 
        print(key.contacts[key])
                 ^
``````````````````

Error that should throw when you try to run it :

```
for key in sorted contacts:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can solve it by following -

```
def printAll(contacts):
    print("All names and numbers")
    for key in sorted(contacts):
        print(f'{key} {contacts[key]}')
```

Expected full output of your code -

```
Number for Fred 7239591
Names for 3841212: Mary Bob 
All names and numbers
Bob 3841212
Fred 7239591
Mary 3841212
Sarch 2213278
```